# Input biasing and coupling calculations

Tags: operational-amplifier, capacitor, impedance, bias, coupling

I have a low frequency input signal 3-80 Hz that I am feeding into an inverting op-amp input. I am slightly confused as to what values I should choose for the following components - R3, C2, R4:

[image]

1. The green section is my voltage follower biasing circuit. Assuming I AC couple the signal, how do I choose the value for the high-pass filter components and DC bias resistor? AFAIK the impedance of the C2 has to be ~1/10 of the input impedance, which in this case is what? R4 (assuming op-amp's input impedance is infinite)?
2. Is R3 needed at all? Won't there be a high pass filter formed with R4 anyway?
3. Should I add a capacitor at the red junction to avoid any AC signals being passed into the non-inverting input?

As always, any suggestions are appreciated!

EDIT:

Just to make it clearer, I know how to calculate HPF values, what I would like to know is how R3 and C2 values should relate to the rest of the circuit considering that C2 is a coupling capacitor. Also, does R4 play any role in the HPF calculations?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/73530/discussion-on-question-by-hypomania-input-biasing-and-coupling-calculations).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the problem with your question...

Say you chose a high-pass cut-off of 3 Hz and fed in 3 Hz. The signal at the inverting input would be 3 dB down on the original signal level. Let's say you had 1 volt p-p and this dropped to 0.7 Vp-p after the filter. That would certainly trigger the comparator to produce a decent enough output square wave.

Now let's say the input frequency was 0.3 Hz - the signal at the inverting input would be 10 times lower at 100 mVp-p and it will still produce a decent square wave output from the comparator.

Where does this end?

If you dropped the frequency to 0.03 Hz, the signal after the filter would be 10 mVp-p and, for a lot of decent comparators, an output square wave would still be produced!

In other words, your idea about filtering the signal is meaningless until you apply hysteresis to limit the size that a signal can drop to whilst still producing a square wave from the comparator.

So, to ask this question you need to specify hysteresis levels, inputs level and what noise you have on the input. Basically, the best answer would be to use a simulation tool.

Go and use a sim tool and add hysteresis and trial it with different levels and see the problems and uncertainties.

But, to answer your edited question, C2 and R4 define the 3 dB point of the high pass filter, fc = 1/(2\$\pi R_4C_2\$). You can largely ignore R3 because C2 will be much more dominant at the low frequency end of the spectrum. But, there's no better answer than a sim other than to build it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, that makes it clearer! So the only impedance that the C2 "sees" is R4, correct? Also, should I choose bigger C2 and smaller R4 or bigger R4 and smaller C2?

Comment: Go for R4 being in the range 1 kohm to 100 kohm - say 10 kohm then for an Fc of 3 Hz, C = 5.3 uF. But you also need to work out what R3 brings to the party for 100% completion.